# What are drawbacks of using a single mapDispatchToProps?

Tags: reactjs, redux

I try to follow the rules of the Redux documentation about presentational/container components and I *connect* my containers using react-redux [connect()](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md#connectmapstatetoprops-mapdispatchtoprops-mergeprops-options). I use mapDispatchToProps and [bindActionCreators](http://redux.js.org/docs/api/bindActionCreators.html) to inject the required actions into a props call *actions*. I never use the second parameter *ownProps*.

As my app became more and more complex, I end up with a lot of mapDispatchToProps() (one for each container) that are almost identical; they bind all actions from almost all action creators.

So I was wondering: what will be the drawbacks to have only one mapDispatchToProps function that bind all actions and use it in each containers?

Something like that:

```
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux'

import * as EventsActionCreators from '../../actions/EventsActionCreators'
import * as TagsActionCreators from '../../actions/TagsActionCreators'
import * as UsersActionCreators from '../../actions/UsersActionCreators'


export default function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
    actions: bindActionCreators(
      {
        ...EventsActionCreators,
        ...TagsActionCreators,
        ...UsersActionCreators,
      },
      dispatch
    ),
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your application is simple enough to warrant this, then I would say go for it. The downsides I see, if any, have to do with your `connects` not being explicit about what actions will be available. To know whats available, you have to go check the definition of `mapDispatchToProps`.

That said, why even have this as a function? `mapDispatchToProps` can receive an object, so in your `mapDispatchToProps.js`, this would suffice:

```
import * as EventsActionCreators from '../../actions/EventsActionCreators'
import * as TagsActionCreators from '../../actions/TagsActionCreators'
import * as UsersActionCreators from '../../actions/UsersActionCreators'

export default {
  ...EventsActionCreators,
  ...TagsActionCreators,
  ...UsersActionCreators,
}
```

then

```
import mapDispatchToProps from './mapDispatchToProps';
import SomeComponent from './SomeComponent';
export ConnectedComponent = connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(SomeComponent);
```